# MS SQL Server dotnet core connection issues

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I'm using ASPNetBoilerplate and attempting to deploy docker images of an ASP.NET MVC/Vue.js app. The app builds and runs fine on development environments with a trusted connection to a local SQL Server. When I try to deploy to docker running on Ubuntu 20 attempting to connect to SQL Server running on a Windows 2019 Server I am consistently getting

> Login failed for user '[removed]'.
> Reason: Password did not mach for the login provided. [Client xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa]

I can use those exact same credentials to connect to the database server using either Azure Data Studio or SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: You state earlier in your question you are using a trusted connection, however, that error is for SQL Authentication. The error is telling you the problem though, the password is wrong.

Comment: perhaps I was unclear. I know the username/password combination is right because I can use it to connect via Azure Data Studio and Management Studio. I know the application has the capability of accessing a SQL Server because it does in development using a trusted connection.

Comment: Then you haven't entered the password correctly in the application. But if youn are supplying a username and password for the connection you *can't* be using a trusted connection. It's username and password *or* trusted connection. YOu aren't passing AD Credentials as a SQL Login, *are you*? If so, that isn't going to work.

Comment: Thanks for responding... here's the connection string, slightly redacted: 

Server=172.16.0.19; Database=****; User Id=****; Password=****

When I use these same credentials through MSSM or Azure Data Studio they work. the database name, user id and password are all literally 4 characters.

Comment: Something *is* wrong, here. The fact is that the password you are provided, for the specified **SQL Login** (not AD) is wrong. You need to provide more information in the question here, including the code you use the connect and an anonymised connection string.

Comment: When connecting with Azure Data Studio or SSMS you're using "Azure Active Directory - Password" authentication instead of "SQL Server Authentication," right?

Comment: I'll see if I can revise my original question for clarity...

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that dotnet core is a bit picky about how a SQL Server is called in the connection string. I had to include the port, even though it is the standard port.

Working Connection String:

Server=172.16.0.19,1433; Database=Db; User Id=Uid; Password=Pass;

Non-working Connecting String, throwing a Login error as listed in the question:

Server=172.16.0.19; Database=Db; User Id=Uid; Password=Pass;

Answer (score 0):

To Use Docker with Asp.net Boiler Plate I try this connection string and it works fro me

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Default": "Server=10.0.75.1,1433; Database=MyProjectDb; User ID=sa;Password=PASSWORD';Trusted_Connection=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"

  },
```

Note : `10.0.75.1` is the default docker internal switch

Answer (score 0):

Both Local & Staging is working
"ConnectionStrings": {
"Default": "Server=host.docker.internal,1433; Database=ms19Db;User=sa; Password=yourStrong(!)Password;"
},